# Fitting a multivariate Gaussian with extremely sparse samples

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fitting, large-data, multivariate-normal-distribution

We have a multi-variate Gaussian distribution. For instance with 3 variables.
The correlations between the variables are important!

We are fitting it to data, however, the samples are such that each sample only has a measurement for *one* of the 3 variables.

For instance:

(1, None, None)

(None, 0, None)

(2, None, None)

(None, None, -1)

This does not fit the usual situation of a "little" missing data, which algorithms such as Expectation Maximization address.

Can we still fit the Gaussian multivariate distribution with a non-diagonal co-variance?

Comment: If your data looks like that, how could you possibly have a correlation between two variables?

Answer (score 1):

With the data you are describing, where at each sample point only one of the vector components is observed, there is no information (meaning **no information at all**) about correlations.  So there is no way you can fit a Gaussian model with non-diagonal covariance matrix.

If you tried with a bayesian model, with a (proper) prior on the covariance matrix, your posterior would be identical to the prior, confirming that there are no sample information.